# comparing mutual information under different constraints

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, information-theory, entropy, mutual-information

Consider a random variable $X$ taking values in $\{0,1,\ldots,n\}$ and $Y$ takes values in $\{0,1\}$.

Let $a_{i}=P\left(X={i}\right), b_{j}=P(Y=j)$.

Also, $ p_{i}=P\left(Y=0 \mid X=x_{i}\right), q_{i}=1-p_{i}$. Then $b_{0}=(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{p})$ and $b_{1}=(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{q})$.

Assume that $p_i < p_{i+1}.$

Consider maximizing the mutual information $I(X ; Y)$ between $X$ and $Y$ given below:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(X ; Y) &=\sum_{x, y} P_{x} P_{y \mid x} \log \frac{P_{y \mid x}}{P_{y}} \\
&=\sum_{i} a_{i}\left(p_{i} \log \frac{p_{i}}{b_{0}}+q_{i} \log \frac{q_{i}}{b_{1}}\right) \
\end{aligned}
$$

If there are no constraints on $\mathbf{a}$, the mutual information $I(X ; Y)$ is maximized when $\mathbf{a}=\left(x_{0}, 0,0, \cdots, 0, x_{n}\right)$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4264439/calculate-capacity-of-a-channel-with-given-transition-probability-matrix). Thus, in the optimal case all masses are zero except at the end points.

I am interested to know how the mutual information $I(X ; Y)$ changes when the distribution $\mathbf{a}$ has more non-zero mass points. Consider the following sequence of distributions:

- $\mathbf{a}_1= $n$ \times Bern(r_1)$.
- $\mathbf{a}_2= \frac{n}{2} \times Binomial(2,r_2)$.
- $\mathbf{a}_3= \frac{n}{3} \times Binomial(3,r_3)$.

$\vdots$

So in general, *assuming $i$ divides $n$ perfectly,* $\mathbf{a}_i= \frac{n}{i} \times Binomial(i,r_i)$. In each case, we can optimize $r_i$ to maximize mutual information. Note that across all cases, $a_1$ leads to the maximum mutual information with $r_1$ optimally chosen.

**Is it true to claim that the the  maximum of mutual information $I(X ; Y)$ under input distribution $\mathbf{a}_i$ is greater than the maximum of $I(X ; Y)$ under $\mathbf{a}_{i+1}$.**

Comment: Your "constraints" are trivially irrelevant in this scenario, as they all include the unconstrained optimal.

Comment: @leonbloy What I was trying to say is that as we add more non-zero points to the $\textbf{a}$,  the mutual information decreases as the non-zero points are far from the extreme ends.

Comment: @leonbloy I edited the question to fix the mistakes and make it more clear.